# Add detail disclosure to UITableViewCell upon action?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView filled with cells that contain collection views. I am needing to press a button in my Navigation bar that will then add a detail disclosure button to all of my cells. This should then enable me to tap that and push me to a new view controller.

Is there a way to animate this action onto all of my table view cells so that a user can either show or hide that functionality at the tap of a button?

Comment: Are you wanting to add a detail disclosure button to the table view cells or collection view cells?

Comment: To the table view cell. Each table view cell has a collection view in it that takes up the entire width of the screen. I need each collection view to essentially animate left and then a detail disclosure button should appear. Then a user should be able to tap that disclosure button.

Comment: Editing my answer to match this comment.

Answer (score 1):

**Not Exactly what u looking for but logic will be like this:**

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *dataArr;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *checksArr;

@end
```

And In your **YourViewController.m** file

```
@implementation YourViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.checksArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i=0; i<self.dataArr.count; i++) {
        [self.checksArr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
    }
}


#pragma mark - TableView Datasource
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }
        if([[self.checksArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue]) {
           [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton];
        }

    return cell;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [self.dataArr count];
}


-(void) btnNavigationBarTapped:(id)sender {
    for (int i=0; i<self.dataArr.count; i++) {
            [self.checksArr replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
        }
    [self.tableview reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to show/hide custom disclosure indicators on each of your `UICollectionViewCell` instances:

In your `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` method, configure your cells to either show or hide the disclosure indicator based on some state variable, so that new cells that get configured as the result of scrolling will have the correct state:

```
MyCollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCellIdentifier"];

// some variable that stores whether to show the indicators
cell.disclosureVisible = self.disclosureIndicatorsVisible;

// Any more setup you need to do with your cell
```

Then, when you tap the button to change the visibility of the indicator, you have a few options, depending on what you are trying to do:

1. Call `reloadData` on the table view, which should cause all the collection views to refresh.
2. For each visible table view cell, which you can get by calling `[self.tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows]`, get each collection view cell with `[cell.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems]`. Then call a custom method on each cell which performs your animation to show or hide the indicator.

**Edit:** you said in your comment that you want the table view cells to show the detail disclosure indicator. In that case, you probably want to get all the visible cells of the table view as described above and set their `accessoryType` to `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton`. However, `accessoryType` is not an animatable property, so you might need to add a custom property to a `UITableViewCell` subclass that animates showing and hiding of a custom accessory view, which then responds to taps.